# More efficient "First K numbers, that their digit sum is S" algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

The whole problem sounds like:

**"We have 2 numbers on input, K and S. We want to print on output first(lowest) K numbers, while their digit sum is exactly S"**

There is an easy naive algorithm to solve such problem (which I was able to construct and to find). It's principle is to have a function **bigint digitSum(i)**, (I write bigint, because **S** is not anyhow limited, as I want just more effective algorithm...) which will return digit sum of argument number. We will start off from number 0 and always increment by 1, while putting that numbers in the function. If function returns sum same as **S**, print that number and continue, until we print **K** numbers.

Function code is here:

```
bigint digitSum(number){
bigint total = 0;
while(number > 0)
  {
     total += number % 10;
     number /= 10;
  }
return total;
}
```

Algorithm **asymptotic complexity** in Big-O is [image] as [image] is complexity of searching trough the numbers 0,1,2,3...n until we find exactly **K** needed numbers and [image] is complexity of our function to find digit sum, as it always divide number by 10.

Is there any algorithm or way to make it more efficient?? Thanks!

Comment: If you have working code that you want critiqued or improved you should post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

To solve such problems, you have to catch some regularities. For example, build a sequence of the first numbers, for which digit sum is S

```
   S  0  1 .. 9  10  11  12 .. 18   19 20  .. 31 ...
F(S)  0  1 .. 9  19  29  39 .. 99  199 299 .. 4999...
```

We can see that the first number could be found using values

```
M = S div 9
R = S mod 9
```

as

```
F(S) = R(9xM)  ////concatenation of digit R and M 9s
for S=31  M=3,R=4, and
F(31) = 4(9x3) = 4999 //concatenation of 4 and three nines
```

So we can determine the first needed number in O(1).
Then elaborate rules for the next number with the same digit sum (note that often `N(i+1) = N(i) + 9`)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about correctness of your algorithm. You wrote by yourself on the end, that it is just "often" not always. And your algorithm is not working for example for S=17, as:
M = 17 div 9 = 1;
R = S mod 9 = 8;

F(S) = 8*(9*1) = 72, which's digit sum != 17

Comment: @qwerty_ Not multiplication, but concatenation - 89.

Comment: @qwerty_ Step is always divisible by 9, but might be large. For S=7: 7,16,25,34,43,52,61,70,`gap here`106,115,124,133...160,`gap`205

Comment: alright, I see the point now and yes it will work, but the fun or problem part is, to elaborate the algorithm, what to do when you go trough the decimal part, like 9-10, 99-100, 999-1000... but I think, it's just some fun with strings, not much work

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive algorithm that will give you the `K` smallest numbers whose digits sum up to `S`. The complexity is definitely better than your brute force algorithm, although I'm not sure what it would be in big O notation.

The algorithm goes as follows:

- Find all the combinations of nDigits=1 that sum up to `S`
- Then nDigits=2, nDigits=3, ... until count == `K`
- all combinations of nDigit → all combinations of 1 + all combinations of nDigit-1

Here's the code in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] currentCount = {0};
    int k = 10, s = 10;

    for(int n = s/9 ; currentCount[0] != 10 ; n++) {
        digitSum(new StringBuilder(), n, 0, s, k, currentCount);
    }
}

public static void digitSum(StringBuilder subNumber, int nDigit, int currentSum, int s, int k, int[] currentCount) {
    if(nDigit == 0) {
        if(currentSum == s) {
            System.out.println(subNumber);
            currentCount[0]++;
        }
        return;
    }

    if(currentCount[0] == k) return; //if already have k numbers, terminate

    int remaining = s-currentSum;

    if(remaining > nDigit*9) return; //if not enough digits to reach S, terminate

    final int bound = Integer.min(9, remaining); //what's the largest valid digit

    //zero digit is only valid if subNumber != 0
    if(subNumber.length()!=0) digitSum(new StringBuilder(subNumber).append('0'), nDigit-1, currentSum, s, k, currentCount);

    for(int i = 1 ; i <= bound ; i++) digitSum(new StringBuilder(subNumber).append((char)(i+'0')), nDigit-1, currentSum+i, s, k, currentCount);
}
```

**EDIT**
I roughly measured the time complexity, and it is clearly O(N) as seen below:
[image]